# Is there a way to count number of each developers commit by file

Tags: git-log

I am using git shortlog -s, however it shows me the entire project I believe. 
I also used git log --author="TomyLobo" --follow  but, it does not show users commits.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The 2 most common ways of viewing history. You don't need to use the whole name.

`git log --author="Jon"`

will match a commit made by "Jonathan Smith"

`git log --author=Jon`

and

`git log --author=Smith`

would also work. The quotes are optional if you don't need any spaces.